# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:Duplicate entry exception for @JoinTable in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, many-to-many, join

When I tried to save an entity using hibernate, it is giving `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key ...`

This is the association declared in class Preferences

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "selectedLanguages", 
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "preferenceId"), 
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "languageId"))
private List<Language> languages;
```

and this is the table created in mysql server

```
CREATE TABLE `languages` (
  `preferenceId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `languageId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_ipl1uqtuxu2oxu5pddfi6sebl` (`languageId`),
  KEY `FKm18lbdrrxs89ff7pymjalc7ca` (`preferenceId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKhmgypuduucfqf98sf2ymorqpr` FOREIGN KEY (`languageId`) REFERENCES `languages` (`languageId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKm18lbdrrxs89ff7pymjalc7ca` FOREIGN KEY (`preferenceId`) REFERENCES `preferences` (`preferenceId`)
);
```

It shows the language id is unique, that is not the intended behavior as a user can know a few languages and one language can be referenced by many users.

I tried adding `unique=false` in the `inverseJoin` part without success. 
How can I remove that unique constraint for languageId? What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I changed `List<Language>` to `Set<Language>` don't know why. **if anybody know the reason, please post it.